# ubuntu 22.04 - arm-none-eabi GDB complains about missing library

Tags: python, arm

Trying to get arm toolchain working on my fresh installed ubuntu 22.04. After fixing some symlinks for `libncurses` it now complains about missing some shared library for python3.6.

I am sure for regular ubuntu users this is a trivial thing to fix. I am not that person. I already ruined one ubuntu installation by removing and reinstalling python3. So reinstalled everything, and going for take 2

The error message when I try to run the `gdb` client:

```
bp@bp-legion:~/Downloads/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin$ ./arm-none-eabi-gdb --version

./arm-none-eabi-gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have this shared library on my disk here:

```
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
```

I tried to symlink that library to /usr/lib, but then it complains about

```
bp@bp-legion:~/Downloads/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin$ sudo ln -s -f /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
[sudo] password for bp: 
bp@bp-legion:~/Downloads/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin$ ./arm-none-eabi-gdb --version
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f2017abfc00 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

At this point I reinstalled python3 last time, resulting in wrecking my ubuntu installation.

Is there anybody that can tell me how to get latest (11.20) arm toolchain working on ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download and extract source code of python 3.6.15 from [python website](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.15/Python-3.6.15.tar.xz)
2. Prepare necessary dependencies

   `sudo apt install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \ libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev \ libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev \ libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libedit-dev libc6-dev`
3. From extracted folder do:

   `sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations -with-lto --enable-shared` 
   `sudo make sharedinstall` 
   `sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the steps suggested by @Artem Maslov in his previous answer or [steps described here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-18-04/) and then link `PYTHONPATH` to the Lib folder of the extracted Python-3.x folder. Before you build your downloaded Python-3.x files, make sure to find the right dependencies for your version.

In my case (my GDB required Python 3.8), the command to set `PYTHONPATH` looked the following way:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/share/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/dependencies/Python-3.8.14/Lib
```

Then hit

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb --version
```

and if the installation went good, GDB should work.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gdb-multiarch` as `arm-none-eabi-gdb` on Ubuntu22.04.

```sh
sudo apt install -y gdb-multiarch
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gdb-multiarch /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb
arm-none-eabi-gdb --version
```

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Reference: [How can I install "gdb-arm-none-eabi" on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031103/how-can-i-install-gdb-arm-none-eabi-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver/1299843#1299843)